# How to query a list in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 tables in my database, one for **projects members and one for projects**
After authenticating the user I have his ID. In my project members table I have the project ID and the user ID.
I can obtain a list of project members for this user using

```
 var pm = db.ProjectMembers.Where(c=> c.UserID=u.UserID) ;
```

Now my question is how can I get a list of ProjectID from the above list. And then how can I get a list of projects from Project table using the list of ProjectID.

Answer (score 2):

**First part of your question:**

```
var projectIDs = db.ProjectMembers.Where(c=> c.UserID=u.UserID).select(pm=>pm.ProjectID) ;
```

**2nd part:**

if you are using Entity Framework, you should see a property called (project) for every entity of your ProjectMembers list, you can simply ignore my first part of this answer and go directly with this one

```
var projectsList = db.ProjectMembers.Where(c=> c.UserID=u.UserID).select(pm=>pm.Project) ;
```

the property may have a different name, give it a try and let me know what happened.

**note:** that if the retrieved projects were null, then your Entity framework is working wth Eager loading (Google it).
so in order to let the Entity framework generate the proper SQL syntax to retrieve the projects data, add an Include() to your query as the following:

```
var projectsList = db.ProjectMembers.Where(c=> c.UserID=u.UserID).Include("Projects").select(pm=>pm.Project) ;
```